# Is there a way to trigger the Ribbon to run all the ribbon controls' EnabledScripts?

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions

I have a custom Ribbon button that I want to be enabled based on whether or not the current user is in a specific group.

I can set up a boolean variable that will say whether the user is in the right group, which obviously has to be set to `false` at first, and check the current user's groups through a REST API call.  But what if that takes an abnormally long time, maybe a couple seconds, and the user has already clicked on the Items tab in the ribbon that will expose the button.  If the `EnabledScript` check happens at that point, the button will remain disabled, because the variable will still have it's initial `false` value.

If the REST API response lets me know that the user *is* in the correct group, how can I then trigger the Ribbon (specifically the Items tab) to re-execute all the `EnabledScript` validation checks so that my button will become enabled?

For example, if I set my custom action to have:

```
EnabledScript="javascript:MyNamespace.CheckIfUserInGroup();"
```

and I have the following code:

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
MyNamespace.UserIsInGroup = false;

MyNamespace.CheckIfUserInGroup = function () {
    if (MyNamespace.UserIsInGroup) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var uri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser?$select=groups/title&$expand=groups";
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    }).then(function (data) {
        data.d.Groups.results.forEach(function (group) {
            if (group.Title === 'The Right Group') {
                MyNamespace.UserIsInGroup = true;

                // how can I force the Ribbon to revalidate
                // now that I know the button _should_ be enabled?
            }
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        MyNamespace.ShowErrorNotification(err);
    });
});
```

Is there something in `SP.Ribbon`, maybe in the `SP.Ribbon.PageManager` instance, that can do that?